# Struct of Arrays and Cache Associativity

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

What is faster/better in terms of cache coherency? The first case is an array of struct with elements that are used together (note that I use a number of elements of 10000 to indicate that it's about large numbers. The exact number of elements, however, is not known a priory, hence the use of dynamic arrays):

```
struct physics
{
    float3 position;
    float3 velocity;
    float3 acceleration;
    float  mass;
};
std::vector<physics> rigidBodies(10000);
void simulate(float dt)
{
    // for each rigid body [i] calculate
    // position += velocity*dt + 0.5*acceleration*dt*dt;
    // force = acceleration * mass;
    // note that struct members are used together.
}
```

The second case is a struct of arrays:

```
struct physics
{
    std::vector<float3> position(10000);
    std::vector<float3> velocity(10000);
    std::vector<float3> acceleration(10000);
    std::vector<float>  mass(10000);
};
void simulate(float dt)
{
     // for each element [i] in physics calculate
     // position[i] += velocity[i]*dt + 0.5*acceleration[i]*dt*dt;
     // force[i] = acceleration[i]*mass[i];
}
```

In both cases, data is packed tightly, but in the second case, each `std::vector` allocates memory on a different location which can cause cache associativity conflict misses. However, a lot of programmers ([mostly in game development](http://bitsquid.blogspot.nl/2014/09/building-data-oriented-entity-system.html)) recommend using the second case. I've read [This excellent paper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.akkadia.org%2Fdrepper%2Fcpumemory.pdf&ei=rpzLVLXwBc3TaNpp&usg=AFQjCNHusTHdrOCrTp8oD3nrWSg_Pei7QA) about memory, but I'm still not clear on which is a better approach.

Comment: The better approach is the one that makes more sense semantically. Obviously a struct of arrays makes no sense in this case.

Comment: I think this depends too much on how you access the data. In game development, the first is often used to pass vertex attribute data to the gpu, since they read in large buffers of vertices at once. Also since it doesn't seem like a ton of work to try both approaches, just see what meets your performance requirements.

Comment: @Griwes: Thank you. Unfortunately things that make sense semantically or are more intuitive, often don't necessarily yield better performance from hardware point of view. And that's exactly what I'm not sure about in this specific example regarding cache performance.

Comment: The second approach is about vectorization; updating all positions and velocities can be done with SSE instructions (or similar, depending on arch) in that layout but not in the first. This comes at the cost of unwieldy code.